# Mui v5 [Select] option container scroll is not working in small screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

Mui select : I have long list of option and my screen have limited height so I am expecting that select option container should have scroll to see all the option, but mui select scrolling is not working in small screen , my custom dispaly have 1080*1920 dimension.

I also cheked in the mui site by inspecting , but in this size scrolling is also not working in their offical site.

Any help will be apppricited.

Thanks

```
      <Select
        value={value ? value : ""}
        name={fieldName}
        className="kioskInput"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
        sx={{ fontSize: "2rem", borderRadius: "10px" }}
        onChange={handleChange}
        displayEmpty
        MenuProps={{ PaperProps: { style: { maxHeight: 500, overflowY: "scroll" } } }}
      >
        {options?.length &&
          options.map(({ label, value }) => (
            <MenuItem sx={Styles.selectStyle} value={value} key={value}>
              {label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Select>
```

[image: my component screen]